# Tableau - Creating Overlapping Date Bins

Tags: tableau-api, dateadd, datepart

I have a report that will be updated Monday through Friday and want to display a single metric [Productivity %] across several different date [In_Date] "bins" i.e. a generated date dimension that would bin my data according to the following definitions:

1. Yesterday
2. Week to date (e.g. on Thursday, Sunday through Wednesday
   data would be displayed etc.)
3. Last 7 days
4. Month to date
5. Last full month
6. Last 3 months
7. Last 6 months
8. Last 12 months

I'm not looking to create a parameter that the user would use to toggle; rather, I want a new dimension that would be dropped in the columns section that would follow the bins outlined above.

Below is an illustration of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Currently, I have the below result using this code:

`IF [In Date] = DATEADD('day', -1, TODAY()) THEN 'Yesterday'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < TODAY() AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('day', -ISOWEEKDAY(TODAY()), TODAY()) then 'Week to Date'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < TODAY() AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('day', -7, TODAY()) THEN 'Last 7 Days'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < TODAY() AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('day', -day(TODAY())+1, TODAY()) then 'Month to Date'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('month', -1, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then 'Last Month'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('month', -3, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then 'Last 3 Months'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('month', -6, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then 'Last 6 Months'`

`ELSEIF [In Date] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [In Date] >= DATEADD('month', -12, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then 'Last 12 Months'`
`ELSE 'Older' END`

[image]

The overlapping date bins are not capturing all of the data: "last 12 months" omits metrics previously captured in the "last 6 months," etc. Moreover, the first 4 bins (yesterday, WTD, last 7 days, and MTD) are missing entirely.

Comment: Tableau's existing date functions already allow essentially all of this. Why do you even need special functions or new columns when you can already get all these from the date selector?

Comment: If you are looking for some overlapping metrics i.e. a calculated field having many to many mapping, that will be a difficult part to do unless a program language is used.  Calculated field can map only one to one.  One input(date) cannot be mapped with many results (values), without hardcoding.  A function can have only one image as per its definition in mathematics. However if you create multiple non-overlapping fields from one input(date) and then combine all these in one dashboard but not in a single field.  Let's watch.  Perhaps I may be able to learn something new.

Comment: Try to imagine what you are trying to create in a simple table.  Date field is your one column.  Now you are trying to calculate another column where one date is say yesterday's date is mapped with multiple values, 4 precisely yesterday, wtd, last7 and mtd.  That is only possible when one row is repeated four times. This type of relationship is called many to many relationship.  Moreover this you want dynamic.  Let's wait for experts if a solution can be proposed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proper case of use of **PARAMETERS** in Tableau.  I enjoyed while solving this.

Since you have not provided any data, I created a dummy data in excel by generating dates from 1-7-2020 onwards till date (`DATE_GIVEN`) and filling some random numbers against these as `MEASURE_1`.  Something like this.

[image]

Now proceed like this.

**Step-1** Create a parameters with 8 inputs (as listed in your question).  I created for first 6 and leaving remaining for you.  The parameter should be like

[image]

**Step-2**  Create a calculated field `date bins` with the following calculation

```
CASE [Parameter 1]
WHEN 1 THEN (
IF [Date_Given] = DATEADD('day', -1, TODAY()) THEN [Date_Given] end)
WHEN 2 THEN 
( IF [Date_Given] < TODAY() AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('day', -ISOWEEKDAY(TODAY()), TODAY()) then [Date_Given] END )
WHEN 3 then
( IF [Date_Given] < TODAY() AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('day', -7, TODAY()) THEN [Date_Given] END )
WHEN 4 THEN
( IF [Date_Given] < TODAY() AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('day', -day(TODAY())+1, TODAY()) then [Date_Given] END )
WHEN 5 THEN
( IF [Date_Given] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('month', -1, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then [Date_Given] END)
WHEN 6 THEN
( IF [Date_Given] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('month', -3, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then [Date_Given] END)
END
```

Needless to say you have to incorporate appropriate calculation for remaining two values

**Step-3** Place `date bins` on rows shelf and additionally on **FILTERS CARD**.  (*Filter out only null values from this .. special values tab*).  Add `measure_1` to desired type.  Show `parameter 1` and your view is ready.  Check the screenshots (Today's system date - 16-12-2020)

[image]

OR

[image]

OR

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: This is right on track with what I need. The only thing is I'm not looking for a parameter, rather a new dimension that would bin the dates for me. I want to drop the field in the columns section for the new headers as listed in the original post.

Comment: Not able to understand, can you please include your desired output in text table or handwritten?

Comment: I have edited my original post with clarifications. thank you for your help up to this point!

Comment: Please also add a view of your data structure!

Answer (score 0):

As regards your edited question, I propose a workaround (*because creation of a calculated field where one value input can result in multiple value outputs seems illogical and impossible to me given the basic rules of mathematics*) as follows.

Create 8 different calculated fields as

`Last 3 months M`

```
IF [Date_Given] < DATETRUNC('month', TODAY()) AND [Date_Given] >= DATEADD('month', -3, DATETRUNC('month', TODAY())) then [Measure_1] END
```

similarly for other desired bins create a separate calculated field.  You can thereafter build a view/viz as included in your question.

[image]

Comment: Did that serve the requirement?